# Physical object(Half white sphere of L40cm W40 and H20cm) not augmented as expected while using vuforia model target

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I made a model target(advanced) of a half sphere for one of my projects where I use a half sphere with some hexagonal holes (5). I used the model target generated using the advanced database and added labels to these 5 spots in Unity. However, when I build my app, It hardly recognises my physical object (and when it does, the labels do not appear on these hollow areas as I did in Unity).

I read according to the documentation, it is not advised to use symmetrical objects like squares, spheres etc.. could it be that since I am using a half sphere, vuforia can't recognise my model target and my overlaid info doesn't show as expected?

Comment: It's difficult to evaluate the exact reason for the poor recognition performance without being able to review the target. However, from your description, the object sounds 'geometry poor' and thus may not be a good candidated for Model Targets. Since you're using an Advanced Model Target, my guess is that some of the detection angles work (POVs where there is sufficient geometry to detect) and some don't.